# How to convert a Spark DataFrame to RDD of POJOs in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I am very new to Spark. I want to convert a DataFrame to a RDD of POJOs. Like:

```
JavaRDD<POJOClass> data = df.toJavaRDD();
```

where df is a DataFrame.

`df.show()` gives:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+                                       
|    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|603300042|     1025|        2|127000948|
|603303766|     1112|        2|127000364|
|603302691|     1184|        2|127000853|
|603303766|     1112|        2|127000364|
|603302691|     1184|        2|127000853|
|603303766|     1112|        2|127000364|
|603303787|     1041|        2|137000323|
|603306351|     1041|        2|137000468|
|603304009|     1307|        2|137000788|
|603303830|     1041|        2|137000012|
|603301119|     1002|        2|137000369|
|603301507|     1188|        2|137001568|
|603302168|     1041|        2|137000468|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

My POJO class is as follows:

```
public static class POJOClass {
        public Long A;
        public Integer B;
        public Integer C;
        public Long D;
}
```

I know

```
JavaRDD<Row> data = df.toJavaRDD();
```

works well. But is there any workaround for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use map function like below.

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

JavaRDD<POJOClass> data = df.toJavaRDD().map(new Function<Row, POJOClass>() {
        @Override
        public POJOClass call(Row row) {
        POJOClass pojo = new POJOClass();
        pojo.setA(row.getLong(0));
        pojo.setB(row.getInt(1));
        pojo.setC(row.getInt(2));
        pojo.setD(row.getLong(3));
        return pojo;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataset

```
public static class POJOClass implements serializable{
        public Long A;
        public Integer B;
        public Integer C;
        public Long D;
}

     Dataset<POJOClass> pojos = context.read().json("/data.json").as(Encoders.bean(POJOClass.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
    JavaPairRDD<Long, POJOClass> jpRDD = jdbcDF.toJavaRDD().mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, Long, POJOClass>() {

        public Tuple2<Long, POJOClass> call(Row row) throws Exception {
            POJOClass yourPojo = new POJOClass();
            // Fill your pojo using row.get(index) 
            return new Tuple2<Long, POJOClass>( anIndex , (POJOClass) yourPojo);

        }

    });
```